# How do you get /__refresh webhook in GatsbyJS to refresh page-data.json?

Tags: gatsby

I am running `gatsby-develop` locally and trying to use the `/__refresh` webhook to refresh the content on the page when a change is made in an external CMS. Right now i'm just testing hitting my local webhook manually. This successfully re-runs `sourceNodes` and `createPages`, however, a lot of my data is dynamic and is actually passed as part of the pageContext for dynamically generated pages. For whatever reason, the `page-data.json` that were created for my pages initially using `gatsby develop` (first run) don't get refreshed even though i'm re-creating each page.

Has anyone else come across this?

Answer (score 0):

So I have experienced a similar issue today with gatsby-source-graphql but in my case I was creating pages programmatically with `createPagesStatefully` though as it has been explained [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/#createPagesStatefully) Gatsby does not rebuild page-data.json if you use createPagesStatefully.

So I have switched to `createPages` instead `createPagesStatefully` at gatsby-config.js and now with the `/__refresh` hook it is re-creating the page-data.json.